# The inverse problems of the pedal triangle.

Tags: triangles, maxima-minima, area

**Given a point $P$ inside the $\triangle ABC$, the pedal triangle of $P$ is the triangle whose polygon vertices are the feet of the perpendiculars from $P$ to the side lines.**

As we know that if $P$ is the orthocenter of  $\triangle ABC$, then the perimeter of the pedal triangle of $P$ takes the maximum, and  if $P$ is the circumcenter of  $\triangle ABC$, then the area of the pedal triangle of $P$ takes the maximum.

Naturally, I think that there are the inverse problems of the above problem:

**Given the distances $p, q$, and $r$ between point $P$ and the three sides of $\triangle ABC$, then find the maximum and minimum values of the area and  perimeter of $\triangle ABC$.**

At first, I thought the problem was simple, but I underestimated its difficulty So far, I haven't made any substantial progress. Is there a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D,E,F$ such that $PD\perp BC, PE\perp CA,PF\perp AB$ with $PD=r,PE=p,PF=q$.

Also, $\angle{EPF}=\alpha$ and $\angle{FPD}=\beta$.

[image]

Here, $\alpha,\beta$ have to satisfy $$0\lt \alpha\lt\pi,\qquad 0\lt\beta\lt\pi,\qquad 0\lt 2\pi-\alpha-\beta\lt\pi$$
i.e.
$$0\lt \pi-\beta\lt\alpha\lt\pi$$

Let us first consider the quadrilateral $AFPE$.

Let $\theta=\angle{FEP}$.

By the law of cosines, $$EF^2=p^2+q^2-2pq\cos\alpha$$ and
$$q^2=p^2+EF^2-2pEF\cos\theta$$
so we have
$$EF\cos\theta=\frac{p^2+EF^2-q^2}{2p}=p-q\cos\alpha$$

By the law of sines in $\triangle{AEF}$, $$AF=\frac{EF\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)}{\sin(\pi-\alpha)}=\frac{EF\cos\theta}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{p-q\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}$$
Similarly, we get
$$AE=\frac{q-p\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}$$
$$BF=\frac{r-q\cos\beta}{\sin\beta},\qquad BD=\frac{q-r\cos\beta}{\sin\beta}$$
$$CE=\frac{r-p\cos(2\pi-\alpha-\beta)}{\sin(2\pi-\alpha-\beta)}=\frac{-r+p\cos(\alpha+\beta)}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)},\qquad CD=\frac{-p+r\cos(\alpha+\beta)}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}$$

---

(1) **Perimeter**

Let $L(\alpha,\beta)$ be the perimeter of $\triangle{ABC}$ where $0\lt\pi-\beta\lt\alpha\lt \pi$.

$$L(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{(p+q)(1-\cos\alpha)}{\sin\alpha}+\frac{(q+r)(1-\cos\beta)}{\sin\beta}-\frac{(p+r)(1-\cos(\alpha+\beta))}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}$$

Let $F(\alpha)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\alpha}$. Then, we have
$$F(\alpha)=\frac{p+q}{1+\cos\alpha}-\frac{p+r}{1+\cos(\alpha+\beta)}$$
$$F'(\alpha)=\frac{(p+q)\sin\alpha}{(1+\cos\alpha)^2}+\frac{(p+r)\overbrace{(-\sin(\alpha+\beta))}^{\text{positive}}}{(1+\cos(\alpha+\beta))^2}\gt 0$$
So, $F(\alpha)$ is increasing with
$$\lim_{\alpha\to\pi-\beta}F(\alpha)=-\infty,\qquad \lim_{\alpha\to\pi}F(\alpha)=+\infty$$

So, there is only one $\alpha$ such that $F(\alpha)=0$.

Letting $G(\beta)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\beta}$, we have
$$G(\beta)=\frac{q+r}{1+\cos\beta}-\frac{p+r}{1+\cos(\alpha+\beta)}$$
$$G'(\beta)=\frac{(q+r)\sin\beta}{(1+\cos\beta)^2}+\frac{(p+r)\overbrace{(-\sin(\alpha+\beta))}^{\text{positive}}}{(1+\cos(\alpha+\beta))^2}>0$$
So, $G(\beta)$ is increasing with
$$\lim_{\beta\to\pi-\alpha}G(\beta)=-\infty,\qquad \lim_{\beta\to \pi}G(\beta)=+\infty$$

which implies that there is only one $\beta$ such that $G(\beta)=0$.

We see that there is no maximum (Paul Sinclair has already provided a good answer on this).

The minimum of $L(\alpha,\beta)$ is $L(\alpha_0,\beta_0)$ where $(\alpha_0,\beta_0)$ is *the only one solution* of
$$\frac{p+q}{1+\cos\alpha}=\frac{q+r}{1+\cos\beta}=\frac{p+r}{1+\cos(\alpha+\beta)}$$

**Example** : If $p=2,q=3$ and $r=4$, then $$\alpha_0\approx 2.19202,\qquad \beta_0\approx 1.99857$$(see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%282%2B3%29%2F%281%2Bcos%28a%29%29%3D%283%2B4%29%2F%281%2Bcos%28b%29%29%3D%282%2B4%29%2F%281%2Bcos%28a%2Bb%29%29+and+0%3Cpi-b%3Ca%3Cpi)). So, the minimum of $L(\alpha,\beta)$ is approximately $30.983$.

---

(2) **Area**

Let $S(\alpha,\beta)$ be the area of $\triangle{ABC}$ where $0\lt\pi-\beta\lt\alpha\lt \pi$.

We have
$$S(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{qAF}{2}+\frac{pAE}{2}+\frac{qBF}{2}+\frac{rBD}{2}+\frac{pCE}{2}+\frac{rCD}{2}$$
$$=\frac{2pq-(p^2+q^2)\cos\alpha}{2\sin\alpha}+\frac{2qr-(q^2+r^2)\cos\beta}{2\sin\beta}-\frac{2pr-(p^2+r^2)\cos(\alpha+\beta)}{2\sin(\alpha+\beta)}$$

Let $H(\alpha)=\frac{\partial S}{\partial\alpha}$. Then,
$$H(\alpha)=\frac{p^2+q^2-2pq\cos\alpha}{2\sin^2\alpha}-\frac{p^2+r^2-2pr\cos(\alpha+\beta)}{2\sin^2(\alpha+\beta)}$$
with
$$\lim_{\alpha\to \pi-\beta}H(\alpha)=-\infty,\qquad \lim_{\alpha\to \pi}H(\alpha)=+\infty$$
So, there is at least one $\alpha$ such that $H(\alpha)=0$.

Let $I(\beta)=\frac{\partial S}{\partial\beta}$. Then,
$$I(\beta)=\frac{q^2+r^2-2qr\cos\beta}{2\sin^2\beta}-\frac{p^2+r^2-2pr\cos(\alpha+\beta)}{2\sin^2(\alpha+\beta)}$$
with
$$\lim_{\beta\to\pi-\alpha}I(\beta)=-\infty,\qquad \lim_{\beta\to\pi}I(\beta)=+\infty$$

which implies that there is at least one $\beta$ such that $I(\beta)=0$.

We see that there is no maximum.

The minimum of $S(\alpha,\beta)$ is $S(\alpha_0,\beta_0)$ where $(\alpha_0,\beta_0)$ is *one of the solutions* of
$$\frac{p^2+q^2-2pq\cos\alpha}{2\sin^2\alpha}=\frac{q^2+r^2-2qr\cos\beta}{2\sin^2\beta}=\frac{p^2+r^2-2pr\cos(\alpha+\beta)}{2\sin^2(\alpha+\beta)}$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider a clock face with $P$ as its center, with three hands of length $p, q, r$. At the ends of the hands, we attach perpendicular lines $\ell_p, \ell_q, \ell_r$. The intersections of these lines with each other provide the points $A, B, C$ of the "anti-pedal" triangle.

Any orientations of the three hands where no two are parallel will give such a triangle meeting your conditions - except for $P$ being inside the triangle, which requires the angle between any two adjacent hands to be $< \pi$. But consider what happens when two are the hands are nearly parallel to each other, while the third is almost anti-parallel to the other two. $\triangle ABC$ becomes huge, with both area and perimeter approaching $\infty$.

There is no maximum on either the area or perimeter.

Comment: There is, however, a minimum,

Comment: Nice idea，how about the minimum value?

Comment: I haven't attempted to calculate it. But it must exist as we have continuous functions that are bounded below by $0$ and which go to $\infty$ in the unbounded directions, Likely the same techniques you were using to search for a maximum will work much better when looking for a minimum.

Comment: I think the minimum value may not be easy to find using the method you mentioned.

Comment: What I described was a means to see that the size of the triangle is unbounded above, not of finding minimums. However, you can use it to define area or perimeter as a function of the two angles the shorter hands make with the longer (measured in opposite directions). The sum of those angles must be $>\pi$ while each is $<\pi$ for $P$ to be interiior of the triangle. The function will be amenable to the minimizing techniques of calculus, thus allowing the problem to be solved in that way.

Comment: The minimum is $0$.  Let $p<q<r$ and chose any angle between $p$ and $r$.  Let $A$ be the intersection between the two lines perpendicular to $p$ and $r$.  Now it's possible to place $q$ that $A$ belongs the perpendicular to $q$ as well.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe - the conditions require that $P$ be interior to the triangle. Not every combination of positions of the three "hands" accomplishes this. Among triangles with $P$ inside, there is a non-zero minimum.